# Word's lower part of save panel is off-screen

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

Working with Word on OS X El Capitan, I spent some time in the "no menu bar" OS X mode:

[image]

It efficiently hides the OS X menu bar and I was happy to have a few pixels more of real estate when writing.

**But now Word's save panel buttons are always off-screen**, even when I set back OS X to normal menu bar mode:

[image]

I can save by hitting Enter or Return, and cancel with Escape, but this is not funny...

Of course I've tried many voodoo window resizings, with and without the menu bar, but nothing got Word to behave normal again.

Note that when writing, the document window is ok:

[image]

It's only when **saving** that the bottom part of the window is not visible.

Do I have to reset Word's preferences or something like that?

My Word version is 2011 14.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this is a dupe somewhere but I can't find it....

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  Drag by any side you can reach, which will shrink from all sides except the one opposite to the side you grab.

You could also change the screen resolution which will force all windows to be pushed inside the screen area - but the first way is simpler.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, unfortunately. While the save panel is opened, doing this does indeed force the document window to resize *but* the save panel itself doesn't resize, and its buttons are still off-screen. When I cancel the save panel the document window is indeed shrunk, but if I do save again, still the same issue with the panel. // I thought this is maybe more an OS X issue than a Word issue, but I don't have this problem with other apps, so Word is definitely guilty here.

Comment: It ought to work just as well to resize the file-picker dialog - & if that's what you're hovering over, shouldn't touch any other window behind it. Just tested again to make sure, is working fine for Word file-pickers, same as any other.

Comment: Oh, excellent, I must have misclicked the first times because now this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the caret next to the box for the change of name. One click will give you a reduced Save As dialogue; two clicks will give you the full Save As dialogue box. However, you have to do this each time; I haven't been able to find a permanent fix.